# How to format time interval offset from 00:00 in HH:MM using DateComponentsFormatter

Tags: ios, swift5, date-format, timezone-offset, dateformatter

I have a value in milliseconds that I want to display in HH:MM format

Example:

- I have input given as 0 and output should be 00:00
- If input is 3600000, output I need is 01:00

I tried below logic but, didn't work.

```
    func secondsToHourMinFormat(time: TimeInterval) -> String {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute]
        return formatter.string(from: time) 
    }
```

Comment: Please state the actual problem (possible input, desired output) without telling _us_ how to "solve" the problem. If you knew DateComponentsFormatter was the way to get this result, you wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: @matt I editted the question attaching my version of logic. Hope this helps in clear understanding of my doubt.

Comment: That's a much better way, showing us _your_ code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is almost right, you just have a couple of omissions.

1. A `TimeInterval` is in seconds are you are passing milliseconds, so you need to divide by 1000
2. You need to set the `.zeroFormattingBehaviour` to `.pad` so that you don't get zero suppression in your output
3. You need to handle the optional return from `string(from:)` somehow; I have changed your function to return a `String?`

```
func secondsToHourMinFormat(time: TimeInterval) -> String? {
    let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute]
    formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
    return formatter.string(from: time/1000)
}
```

Comment: Can you work out how to do this with the new `.formatted` call? I've been banging away at it and I just haven't a clue.

Comment: I have beta Xcode, but I don't have any beta devices to test on yet.

Comment: I see how to do a time interval formatter, but I don't see how to tell it to dictate the zero formatting, how to allow just the hour and minute, etc. It's weird stuff.

Comment: It seems that using `.timeDuration` doesn't really let you customise the format - It is a static property on `Date.ComponentsFormatStyle`.  I tried creating my own formatter but it didn't have the right options either.  I got closer creating a date for "midnight" and adding `time/1000` - Then I could use `.formatted(.dateTime.hour(.twoDigitsNoAMPM).minute(.twoDigits))` - But I could't force 24 hour hours, so I was getting 12 instead of 0.  I think my current answer is easier than the new hotness :)

Comment: It sounds like you went through just the same process I did, and came to exactly the same conclusions. I'm glad I'm not alone. :) The date for midnight solution can't work, because what if the right answer is 40 hours? This is an _interval_, not a clock time; your answer captures that, and I can't find a way to do the same kind of formatting with `dateRange.formatted(.interval)`.